# How to configure Upload file Pop Window ? HTML

Tags: html

I already know how to create an upload file pop windows, and restricting that I will upload an image only, I was just wondering if it's possible to remove the dropdown box showing "Image" and "All files". is there a code that I should do to remove the "all files" in the drop-down?

Comment: follow up question is, now that i can only select the image file only, when i made a multiple accept of jpg, png, gif, the dropdown shows "Custom Files", can i rename that into (.jpg, .png, .gif)?

Comment: Sorry, that's not handled by the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#attr-input-accept). Closest you can get is `<input type="file" accept="image/*">` which is what you probably have right now anyway.

Comment: yes i already have that. in the drop down it shows "Image Files" and the "All Files", is it possible to remove "All Files"?

Comment: It's not possible, as this is controlled by the browser and is browser specific (some browsers do not support the accept attribute). You can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8941416) answer for a follow-up.

Comment: is that so. how sad . haha. well anyway, just wondering if that's possible hehe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**maybe this is your answer**

Just do not catch your question, But maybe this is your answer

```
<input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg" />
```

> *Some browsers does not support this command 
>   Still others are supported but do not show in the drop-down list only what is acceptable formats*

[image: Firefox drop down list show formats what is accpted]

**And never trust your user, just validate user send by a server side language like PHP**